# Issue pulling data from xml with etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, django, xml, elementtree

I'm working with JMDict (https://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/j_jmdict.html). Here is a little example of the data I'm having trouble with:

```
<entry>
<ent_seq>1265070</ent_seq>
<k_ele>
<keb>古い</keb>
<ke_pri>ichi1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>news1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>nf16</ke_pri>
</k_ele>
<k_ele>
<keb>故い</keb>
</k_ele>
<k_ele>
<keb>旧い</keb>
</k_ele>
<r_ele>
<reb>ふるい</reb>
<re_pri>ichi1</re_pri>
<re_pri>news1</re_pri>
<re_pri>nf16</re_pri>
</r_ele>
<sense>
<pos>&adj-i;</pos>
<s_inf>of things, not people</s_inf>
<gloss lang="eng">old</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">aged</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">ancient</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">antiquated</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">antique</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">timeworn</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<pos>&adj-i;</pos>
<gloss lang="eng">long</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">since long ago</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">time-honored</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<pos>&adj-i;</pos>
<gloss lang="eng">of the distant past</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">long-ago</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<pos>&adj-i;</pos>
<gloss lang="eng">stale</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">threadbare</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">hackneyed</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">corny</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<pos>&adj-i;</pos>
<gloss lang="eng">old-fashioned</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">outmoded</gloss>
<gloss lang="eng">out-of-date</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="dut">oud</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="dut">aloud</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">verouderd</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">oubollig</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">gedateerd</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">ouderwets</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">oudmodisch</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">archaïsch</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">antiek</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">{i.h.b.} afgezaagd</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="dut">niet vers</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">onfris</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">belegen</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">oud</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">oudbakken</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">verschaald</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">muf</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="dut">gebruikt</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">afgewerkt</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">sleets</gloss>
<gloss lang="dut">versleten</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="fre">vieux (sauf pour les personnes)</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">âgé</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">ancien</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">antique</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">vieilli</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">vieillot</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">caduque</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">démodé</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">obsolète</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">passé</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">vicié</gloss>
<gloss lang="fre">usé</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">alt</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">altertümlich</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">langjährig</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">sich über lange Zeit erstreckend</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">altehrwürdig</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">althergebracht</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">ehemalig</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">noch nicht reformiert</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">in der alten Version</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">altmodisch</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">veraltet</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">altbacken</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">unmodern</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">abgestanden</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">abgenutzt</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="ger">alterserfahren</gloss>
<gloss lang="ger">routiniert</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="hun">öreg</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">régi</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">divatjamúlt</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">elavult</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">állott</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">áporodott</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">banális</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">elcsépelt</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">elévült</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">nem friss</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">poshadt</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">foszlott</gloss>
<gloss lang="hun">kopott</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="rus">старый</gloss>
<gloss lang="rus">1) старый</gloss>
<gloss lang="rus">(ср.) ふるく</gloss>
<gloss lang="rus">2) устарелый, отсталый</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="slv">star (za predmete)</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="spa">(objetos) viejo</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">antiguo</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">anticuado</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">antigüedad</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">articulo obsoleto</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">(objeto) viejo</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">antiguo</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">anticuado</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">antigüedad</gloss>
<gloss lang="spa">articulo obsoleto</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss lang="swe">gammal</gloss>
</sense>
</entry>
```

I'm working with Django and etree.ElementTree for pulling data.
Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
treeW = ET.parse('D:\Dev\kanjitest\kanjitest\static\dbxml\JMdict.xml')
rootW = treeW.getroot()

wordsKanjiXml = rootW.findall(".//entry")
entryId =0
for wordsKanjiEntry in wordsKanjiXml:
    entry = {}
    entryKanji =''
    entryKana =''
    entryMeanings = []
    # -------------
    for parts in wordsKanjiEntry:
        sensesList=[]
        if parts.tag == 'k_ele':
            for kanji in parts:
                if kanji.tag == 'keb':
                    entryKanji=kanji.text
                                                
        if parts.tag=='sense':
           
            for sense in parts:
                if sense.tag == 'gloss':
                    if 'spa' in sense.attrib.values():
                        sensesList.append(sense.text)
                        
        if sensesList:
            entryMeanings=sensesList
        
        if parts.tag == 'r_ele':
            for kana in parts:
                if kana.tag == 'reb':
                    entryKana=kana.text
    # -------------
    
    entryId =entryId+1
       
    entry=dict(
        kanji = entryKanji,
        kana = entryKana,
        meanings = entryMeanings
    )
    if literal in entryKanji:
        words.append(entry)
```

So, the problem is in the final conditional. `literal` is a variable in another part of the code containing a Chinese character in a string. For instance, 古. So, if a word contains that specific string, the entry will be added to a list called `words`. The problem is whith entries with multiple writings for the same word (as the xml example I posted). 古い can be written '古い', or '故い', or '旧い'. As it has several `<keb>` tags, it seems that the conditional is not applying, even if one of them is actually true. I don't know if I'm explaining my self well enough but I hope someone understands and help me with refining that final conditional so if any of the `<keb>` tags contain `literal`, the code runs.

Comment: You should be appending to the entry as `entryKanji += kanji.text` or make `entryKanji` a list

Comment: You can upvote the answer too if you wish :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the last value of `entryKanji` is present so it may or may not match the value in `literal`.
Making `entryKanji` a list and testing with `literal='古'`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
treeW = ET.parse('/home/luis/tmp/test.xml')
rootW = treeW.getroot()
literal='古'
words = []
wordsKanjiXml = rootW.findall(".//entry")
entryId =0
for wordsKanjiEntry in wordsKanjiXml:
    entry = {}
    entryKanji =[]
    entryKana =''
    entryMeanings = []
    # -------------
    for parts in wordsKanjiEntry:
        sensesList=[]
        if parts.tag == 'k_ele':
            for kanji in parts:
                if kanji.tag == 'keb':
                    entryKanji.append(kanji.text)
                                                
        if parts.tag=='sense':
           
            for sense in parts:
                if sense.tag == 'gloss':
                    if 'spa' in sense.attrib.values():
                        sensesList.append(sense.text)
                        
        if sensesList:
            entryMeanings=sensesList
        
        if parts.tag == 'r_ele':
            for kana in parts:
                if kana.tag == 'reb':
                    entryKana=kana.text
    # -------------
    
    entryId =entryId+1
       
    entry=dict(
        kanji = entryKanji,
        kana = entryKana,
        meanings = entryMeanings
    )
    
    if literal in ''.join(entryKanji) :
        words.append(entry)
        
    print(words)
```

Result:

```
[{'kanji': ['古い', '故い', '旧い'], 'kana': 'ふるい', 'meanings': []}]
```

Making a list of XML entities to check also works

```
entryKanji =[]
entryKanjiEnt =[]

# existing code

            for kanji in parts:
            if kanji.tag == 'keb':
                entryKanji.append(kanji.text)
                entryKanjiEnt.append(kanji.text.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
# existing code

if b''.join(entryKanjiEnt).find(literal.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')) != -1:
    words.append(entry)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. However, is there a way it sets only the element containing `literal` and just skip other elements on the list?

Comment: I think so, you could try `if literal in kanji.text : entryKanji.append(kanji.text) break` when adding it to the list or the variable since now you want a single value. The break is suggested since means it already found a match, no need to continue looping

Comment: However, if `literal='い'` all items will match, correct?

Comment: That could work on this specific case as 古い is the first item, so list would only contain one element if `literal='古'`, but if `literal='旧'`, then the list will have all three items again so it would be back at the same problem. :(

Comment: So if you need one/any match not all, just pick the first and add he `break`